# laravel queue:work. How to handle long running jobs?

Tags: php, laravel, queue

I have some long running jobs (up to 1h) that get added to my queue regularly.

e.g. `ProcessFileUploads, ProcessExports, etc`

So the queue is stuck when the worker is processing one of those jobs.
Is there some way to allow other jobs to be processed at the same time?

Comment: Is it the same job or are these long running jobs distinct job types?

Comment: They are different types (classes). I know that I could use onQueue and Priorities. But I would prefer actual concurrency

Comment: You can have multiple queues. If you are using horizon, you can have a separate queue with n number of workers for your long running jobs and they won't interfere with the rest of the jobs.